# Spring singleton created, destroyed, created again

Tags: spring

I am seeing a peculiar behavior in Spring 3.2.5

One of my beans is created as a consequence of AbstractBeanFactory#getType

Then Spring throws an exception along the lines of

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'A' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'B' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'B': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

As the result of that exception, my bean is destroyed.

Later, my bean is created again, from a different getType() call. Tghis time Spring does not have any circular path problems.

Eventually, the entire context is created successfully, with the second copy of my bean retained as singleton.

My question is - is that behavior normal? Or am I doing something wrong? My bean has side effects in its init() method, so if this is a normal behavior of Spring, I'll need to add a destroy() method to it...

Edit:

To clarify the questions about the exception: The beans mentioned in exception are not exactly relevant because the context (including the beans A and B) is eventually created successfully, so there really is no circular dependency. However, for the completeness' sake, bean A takes bean B as constructor argument.

Comment: Your singleton is not created and destroyed. It fails at the first creation attempt, because it depends on `B` which has not been created yet and for some reason, it's not possible to create it the first time `A` asks for it. Thus, Spring tries to create it for a second time, successfully. Anyway, the way you posted the question seems so difficult to guess what's going on. How do you inject `B` into `A`?

Comment: @XtremeBiker, the init() method is called twice, on two different objects, of which the second is retained in the context. How is that not "created twice"? I did not verify that destroy method is invoked (I don't have one yet), but I do see destroySingleton called, and that should call destroy method, if I had one.

Comment: Well, maybe I missed in explanation, the object of course is being created, but not assigned to the Spring context, I meant. That's the reason why Spring makes a second attempt.

Comment: `bean A takes bean B as constructor argument`. You could try injecting it using a setter, instead.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, tried - same difference :( that's another puzzle.

Comment: Maybe it's an indirect circular dependency. You say bean A uses B but B is not using A. However, you should take a look at what B is using. Could it B something that require A under the hoods? Or something that can't be acquired in that moment..

Comment: @XtremeBiker, you're "barking up a wrong tree". There is no circular dependency - the context is ultimately successfully created. The exception  is an artifact of the way Spring figures out the type of factory bean.